# Can Blender (2.8) export Third Layer Children to FBX?

Tags: export, parent, .fbx

I have heard that Blender (2.8)'s FBX export has a Mysterious Issue when exporting 'grandchildren' of the Root object.

Is this true?

A particular LOD import system I am working with required grandchildren + naming convention for LODs to be imported.

I have tried, and had a number of issues when using 'grandchildren' in this project, in that: they just don't exist in the project after exporting the FBXs from Blender.

It's all super simple static meshes. No rigs, or animation or anything.

If Blender simply doesn't / can't export deep childing... Then I will have to look elsewhere :(